# Send \n with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a little script that send a textarea content to PHP page with get ajax request:

```
$.get('./data/pages/admin/actions.php?savepost=1','&post_id=' + $(box).attr('id') + '&text=' + new_text,'text');
```

new_text get content from textarea with val();

When I save the text from php it has no \n character. Some1 can solve my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not encoding your data at all, so lots of things are going to blow up (percent signs, ampersands, ...). Either use `encodeURIComponent` on each bit or (and this is easier) let jQuery do it for you:

```
$.get('./data/pages/admin/actions.php?savepost=1', {
    post_id: $(box).attr('id'),
    text:    new_text
}, 'text');
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for details on the data parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the newline character to the right url notation.

Answer (score -2):

before passing `new_text` try doing this first.

```
new_text.replace("\r\n","%0D%0A");
```

Comment: "\n" is just "%0A". "\r\n" (Windows newline) would be "%0D%0A"!

Comment: Yeah... it was too late for me to realize that... and when I tried editing the SO page says under maintenance... sigh...

Comment: In any case, it only addresses a very narrow part of the problem.