# Jquery .val() not returning line-breaks in a textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea, newline, urlencode

I got problem with line breaks in a textarea.

I get the text with .val() function:

```
var messageBody = $('#composeInput').val();
```

This is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'serverScripts/messages/addMessage.php',
    data: 'messageBody='+messageBody+'&invitedJSONText='+invitedJSONText,
    success: function(){
        //Do something
    }
});
```

And PHP:

```
$messageBody = nl2br(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['messageBody']));
```

The text:

> Hi!
>
> How are you?

Becomes:

> Hi! How are you?

If I insert the variable messageBody to an another div-element I can't see any \n is this normal. How do I fix this?

Comment: Topical: [Why does jquery $.ajax remove line breaks in data and $.get doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7017068/2943403)

Comment: And [How do I get my textarea to preserve newlines when using jQuery and JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173166/2943403) and [Send \n with jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2217273/2943403)

Comment: Potentially related: [jQuery: Preserve user-inputted line breaks in <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30982868/2943403)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the `data` parameter is passed as a string, you must URL encode it yourself:

```
'messageBody=' + encodeURIComponent(messageBody) + '&invitedJSONText=' + encodeURIComponent(invitedJSONText)
```

But it is far more simpler to pass the `data` parameter as an object; jQuery encodes the data automatically:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'serverScripts/messages/addMessage.php',
    data: {
        messageBody: messageBody,
        invitedJSONText: invitedJSONText
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#foo").html(data); // <-- did something
    }
});
```

---

PS: instead of `nl2br` you can set CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property to `pre-line` on an element to display newline as newline.

Comment: Thanks this one worked! Do you also know how I can insert `messageBody` to a div element?

Comment: Hammer time: [Textarea .val No Line Breaks when Sending Data via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28157717/2943403) and [Ajax variable ignores line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51537833/2943403) and [How can I use ajax to post message through a url and still keep line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4662021/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at PHP's nl2br function. Newlines characters do not render in the browser, so you have to replace them with line breaks.http://us.php.net/nl

Comment: I see he mentions `nl2br()` in his question.

Comment: Already looked at it. When I look at the get parameters I can't see any \n too?

Answer (score 0):

Is not that a known issue?
http://api.jquery.com/val/

The workaround is using valHooks as explained in the Note section.