# Why does jquery $.ajax remove line breaks in data and $.get doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I call the same PHP script using $.ajax and $.get and get two different results.

$.ajax strips line breaks from data passed through the function while $.get doesn't.

I've tried explicitly setting the dataType to text and html with no luck. Most of the parameters for $.get default to the same in $.ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Is this a bug?

Here is the exact code I use:

```
    $.get("lib/ajax_scripts/set-product-value.php", { input_id: input_id, val:value });

    $.ajax({
            url:"lib/ajax_scripts/set-product-value.php",
            type:'GET',
            data:'input_id='+input_id+'&val='+value});
```

Below is code anyone can try who has access to PHP enabled server and firebug. Look at the firebug response for each request, you will see that `<br />` are added to the $.get and not to $.ajax.

ajaxtest.html

```
<form method="GET" onsubmit="return false">
    <textarea id="data" name="data">a
        b
        c</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">        
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
   var data = $('#data').val();

   $.get("data.php", { data: data });


   $.ajax({
        url:"data.php",
        type:'GET',
        data:'data='+data});

});   
</script>
```

data.php

```
<?php  echo nl2br($_GET['data']); ?>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2

Comment: Can you confirm with Fiddler or Firebug that the response is the same before jQuery gets ahold of it? As the answer below states, $.get is just an alias for $.ajax with some default options.

Comment: @BZink I dunno, I'm guessing it was resolved during the intervening four months.

Comment: Ha. Weird. I didn't notice this was old. It showed up in my RSS feed so I came and checked it out. Thanks.

Comment: The syntax you used in jQuery.get request i.e. `{foo: "bar"}` is also acceptable in jQuery.ajax's data parameter and both will work. Moreover, the "not working" syntax will not work for both methods. See Justin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the same results. According to the docs for [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Moreover, if you look at the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), you can clearly see that `.get` is just a wrapper for `.ajax`:

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
    });
};
});
```

Are you sure you aren't passing other parameters to `jQuery.ajax`? You might want to post the code you are using for each of them, to see if there is something else going on here.

Comment: doesnt get default to `html` content type (hence the shortcut for `getJSON`) which would not strip the line breaks but ignore them unless in a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: According to the docs, both functions have the same default: `Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)` - you can also see from the source code above that `get` is just a pass-through to `ajax`.

Comment: It's a longshot, but try passing the same input to `data` in both calls - for example, `{ input_id: input_id, val:value }`

Comment: I've tried, no luck. It's just plain text too, no code is being passed.

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately I do not see any other difference between the code, using your code samples and the jQuery snippet from above.

Answer (score 2):

$ Ajax returned text that were missing line breaks when I appended it to my html.  Since I wanted to save the formatting, I had to put tags in it.  So I used the string function replace like this:

var part1 = /\n/g;

var newc_data = old_data.replace(part1,"< br >") ;

This is probably a good reason to avoid text as a format.  But in my case I want to write some intelligence to convert text to json.