# jQuery textarea value does not work properly with space and return key

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am using PHP with jquery.

I get textarea value by jquery command:

```
$('#textarea_id').val()
```

If i use spaces in textarea, like `My Text` , it only gets `My`.

If i use return key in my textarea like,

`My`

`Text`

It gets as `MyText`

**EDIT:**

It seems `$('#textarea_id').val()` works truly.

Actually, I am using a function call like

```
func1(...,$('#textarea_id').val(),...);
```

and in `func1`, i have:

```
function func1(...,textarea_content,...) {
  $('#textarea_id').load('/test.php?textarea_content=' + textarea_content + ...);
}
```

and also in `test.php` i grab `textarea_content` with `$textarea_content = $_REQUEST['textarea_content'];`

If i use `echo $textarea_content` for viewing textarea content.

in case of `MyText`, it will be ok.

in case of `My Text` it will be  null!.

and in case of

`My`

`Text`

it will be `MyText`

**SOLUTION:**

I found the solution in

[Jquery .val() not returning line-breaks in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534928/jquery-val-not-returning-line-breaks-in-a-textarea)

the solution is : `encodeURIComponent($('#textarea_id').val())`

Many thanks

Comment: Try using $('textarea_id').html()

Comment: @nettle is there a valid reason why we cannot use `val()` or `.prop('value')` ?

Comment: Could it be similar to [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript)?

Comment: The code you posted works really well and it's VALID. You really need to setup a demo with your issue. http://jsbin.com/ixohis/1/edit Edit this one untill you menage to do it wrong :D

Comment: @nettle According to the api, html() will return the initial content of the textarea, not the current, user-edited value.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/7ndM8/ it's either something else or browser specific.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it yourself. That way, it is clear to everyone what the answer is.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to your question title, just add your solution as an answer and accept it once you're able.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy:  It's ok..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in

[Jquery .val() not returning line-breaks in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534928/jquery-val-not-returning-line-breaks-in-a-textarea)

the solution is : `encodeURIComponent($('#textarea_id').val())`