# Textarea .val No Line Breaks when Sending Data via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen a ton of articles about how to add line breaks to the .val, but none of them seem to be working for me. I have tried the jQuery recommended workaround:

```
$.valHooks.textarea = {
  get: function( elem ) {
  return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
  }
};
```

but, no matter what I seem to do, the text still gets smashed together into one line.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <div id="email-info">
    <div id="email-top-row">
        <div id="email-subject-container">
            <label for="email-subject" class="email-labels">Subject:</label>
            <input id="email-subject"></input>
        </div>
        <div id="email-from-container">
            <label for="email-from" class="email-labels">From:</label>
            <input id="email-from"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="email-body-container">
        <label for="email-body" class="email-body">Body:</label>
        <textarea id="email-body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="email" onclick="emailSend()">Send Email</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function emailSend() {
 $.valHooks.textarea = {
  get: function( elem ) {
  return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
  }
 };

 var emailSubject = $('#email-subject').val();
 var emailFrom = $('#email-from').val();
 var emailBody = $('#email-body').val();        

 emailURL = emailURL + '&email_subject=' + emailSubject;
 emailURL = emailURL + '&email_from=' + emailFrom;
 emailURL = emailURL + '&email_body=' + emailBody;

 $.getJSON(emailURL, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 });
}
```

Now, say I add this to the textbox:

```
test line 1

test line 2

test line 3
```

When I do a console.log of that, it comes out in the console correct with the line breaks, but in the network inspector tab, and on our server, what is sent is `test line 1test line 2test line 3`.

I am kinda at a loss of how to add in the line breaks to the url. I have seen a lot of stuff about the '\n' but I have never seen that in my url or in my console logs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you  very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to escape your values coming from your textbox before appending to your url:

```
var emailSubject = encodeURIComponent($('#email-subject').val());
var emailFrom = encodeURIComponent($('#email-from').val());
var emailBody = encodeURIComponent($('#email-body').val());
```

Comment: Note that if you sent the data in a data object instead, jQuery would handle this for you. It would also handle it if you used `$('#theform').serialize();` to build the paramstring.