# jQuery: Preserve user-inputted line breaks in <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I've been scouring Google and SO for hours but can't seem to find an answer to this for the life of me!

All I want to do is preserve the line breaks entered into a `<textarea>` element by the user, to post the content via **a jQuery `$.ajax()` call**. If I simply submit the form to a page as usual, this works, but I've been told by my boss to use REST/AJAX.

Many, many posts on SO and across the net in general mention replacing `\n`'s with `<br />`'s, or using `white-space: pre-wrap;` in the element's CSS. These solutions **do not** work for me as the line breaks simply don't show up in Chrome Developer Tools.

Code snippet:

```
<form id="addPostForm" role="form" method="post" action="/blog">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="5" id="postBody" name="postBody"></textarea>
        ...more input controls
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '#addPostForm', function() {
        var postBody = $(this)[0].postBody.value;
        ...more code
    });
</script>
```

When I enter e.g.:

"This is the first paragraph.

And here is another.

And yet another."

The `postBody` variable's value is:

"This is the first paragraph. And here is another. And yet another."

This is driving me crazy! Surely this shouldn't be as hard as it seems to be!

P.S. I don't think it should make a difference, but just in case anyone is wondering, I'm using Python/Pyramid, Jinja2 and Bootstrap 3 for this project.

Comment: How are you viewing `postBody`'s contents? There is nothing in your shown code that strips out newline characters, so i can only assume you are viewing it in something that doesn't show them, i.e. you wouldn't see the newlines when rendered in a html element, hence why there are suggestions of replacing newlines with `<br>`

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I'm using the Sources tab in Chrome Developer Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops sorry for wasting your time, it was as simple as using `$('#postBody').val()` instead of `$(this)[0].postBody.value`. Thanks anyway to all commenters and answerers!

Comment: That shouldn't have changed anything, as they do the same thing, jQuery's `val` function retrieves the textarea's `.value` property

Comment: I know; this makes no sense to me whatsoever but lo-and-behold it works! Maybe there's some crucial line of code somewhere that causes this, and I'm missing it, but all I know is that I can now see `\r\n`'s in Chrome Dev Tools by using `val()` instead of `value`. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in JS

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "yoururl",
   data: $("#addPostForm").serialize()
   (...)
  });
});
```

In your server side code you can get POST value postBody with original spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to me that this problem stems from the Chrome Dev Tools stripping the line breaks. Change the tool settings, or try something else like firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the lines by '\n' (yes I have tested this) and rejoin them with 
 tags, check this out:

```
$('textarea').val().split('\n')
```

put this in your onclick function and set a breakpoint on it if you are using Chrome, it splits the lines into an array. if you join them with

```
.join('<br>')
```

you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep, using `.val()` is the key, and I've already implemented the rest. But thanks anyway for trying to help :-)