# Ajax variable ignores line breaks

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I´ve got a problem when I try to send the value of a **textarea** through Ajax in Joomla.

The variable looks correct right before the ajax request. But when returned from helper.php, the success response var ignores all the line breaks.

**My jQuery / Ajax:**

```
var curBody = jQuery(this).closest("div").children("div").children('textarea').val();
//var curBody = curBodyVal;//.replace("/\r\n/","<br>");
console.log(curBody);
jQuery.ajax({            
    url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=usernotes&method=edit&format=json&Id="+edit_id+"&body="+curBody,
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**In my helper.php file at the function for the ajax call:**

```
public static function editAjax()
{
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    //$bodyToUpdate = $input->get("body", 'default_value', 'raw');
    $bodyToUpdate = $_GET['body'];

    return($bodyToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "all line breaks are ignored"?  Where/how are you observing this?

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) will help you. Your JavaScript has `\n` as line breaks, when you output with PHP you need to convert those to `<br>` if you want to maintain the line breaks.

Comment: use method as post don't use get for this

Comment: @David sorry, I´ve updated det question, so it´s more clear

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks! I also need to use nl2br() in my SQL query to get it working right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are trying to send values, which are not simple strings, send it ina a POST method instead of GET,

GET is used for simple strings, only used for characters within ASCII character range.

POST is used for any other complicated strings, you can send binary data as well, for example you can send files and images using POST method, but you cannot send using GET method

Change your ajax to this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: { option: "com_ajax", module: "usernotes" , method: "edit", format: "json" , Id: edit_id, body: curBody },
  success: function( response ) {
    console.log(response);
          }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but I´m getting this error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )**

Comment: Why should the OP change their code? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  in GET only ASCII letters allowed, in POST method no restrictions, binary data is also allowed, REFERENCE; https://www.quora.com/HTTP-What-is-the-difference-between-GET-and-POST

Comment: *I know that* @vSugumar, but you need to include that in your original post to make your answer have more value. Right now you're just saying "change it" without explaining what you did.

Comment: After a quick check of your other answers I see that you have a lot of "change this" or "try this" answers. Those are not good answers IMHO because you never explain why.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, Thank you very much for pointing out that, I have edited my answer with little bit of information